# Convert seconds on x axis into min:sec, while keeping the same x limits

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, time

I am plotting values over time, which is in seconds. However, I want to display the time in minutes:seconds on the x-axis. I have done this now, but I get decimals like .8 which you don't want in time notation. I tried to fix it with the `'{}:{}.format(mins, secs)'`, but then my x values become strings and I cannot get the appropriate x lims anymore.

Does anyone know a nice way of converting seconds to min:secs while being able to maintain the same xlims?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


y = np.random.rand(90, 1)

print(y)
    
x = np.arange(1380, 1470, 1)    # seconds
x = x/60                        # minutes


plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Time (mins)')
```

[image: Example]

Comment: have you tried converting to timestamp? I'm not sure about numpy, but pandas handles that pretty easily so it should be similar in numpy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's not a problem for you, I usually use pandas to convert to datetime

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

y = np.random.rand(90, 1)
x = np.arange(1380, 1470, 1)    # seconds
x = x/60                        # minutes
t = pd.to_datetime(x, unit='m') # convert to datetime

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, y)
plt.xlabel('Time (mins)')
fig.autofmt_xdate() # auto format
```

[image]